# Can PhpStorm list shared inheritance / interfaces between classes

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to show any shared inheritance or interfaces between two classes?

Say I have `ClassA` and `ClassB` that both have deep levels of inheritance and interface implementation. Is there some tooling I can use to show me any that are shared between the two?

Comment: In one click/step? I do not think so (I personally know none). Perhaps **class Diagrams** can help here (I've used them quite long time ago but it should be able to show this). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/class-diagram.html You can also try **Hierarchy toolwindow** ... but you would need to remember the tree and then compare it with the same for another class (since it shows this info for a single target class) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/viewing-structure-and-hierarchy-of-the-source-code.html

Comment: Examining the diagrams was about as close as I could find myself yeah :(

Comment: BTW: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-28114 and linked tickets -- they would help here (when they would be implemented of course). Consider voting for/commenting there anyway. More votes increases chances for them to be noticed/implemented.